# What's the correct way to extract brightness out of a JPEG image (gamma corr., etc.)?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, camera, exif

in a nutshell: I can't extract meaningful light intensities out of RGB values from JPEG photos, and trying to account for gamma correction or sRGB only makes matters worse.

I'm doing a toy project, which involves processing a bunch of photo images, shot with an intervalometer. Basically, I want to make a time lapse out of them, with some corrections so that the clips are neater. I use Canon dSLRs.

I need a function, which, given a JPEG file, figures out the "average scene brightness". The result should be a simple number; no need to be expressed in any absolute photometric unit, I'm doing only relative comparisons. So, for example, you take a picture of some room, and the function returns, say, "5.0". Then you add a second light bulb to the lighting, exactly the same type as the first, placed next to it, and shoot again. The function should now give you "10.0".

So, my current implementation of this function combines several things: ISO speed, shutter speed, aperture (extracted from EXIF) and the average image brightness. The Exif stuff is obviously more important, because, in automatic modes, the camera would try to use such and such settings, so the image brightness comes around the mid-gray point.
Yet, the ISO/Shutter/Aperture settings all have a resolution of 1/3 stop or less, thus detecting the image brightness is important for "fine tuning".

As I was doing it, I was getting some visibly bogus results, and the more I dug in, the more puzzled I got. So in the end I set up an "almost serious" experiment:

**Test setup:**
A simple wall in a room, lit with an incandescent lamp, the illumination is quite even.
Used two cameras to compare the results: 5D with a 50mm prime, 350D with a 35mm prime.
Distance to the wall: around 3 metres.
All photos are shot at 1/10 s shutter speed.
Camera settings: manual, "faithful mode" (no enhancements, no saturation or contrast bump), Tungsten WB, no custom functions, JPEG-Fine, sRGB colorspace. The lenses have no filters. The illumination doesn't change, I only vary the ISO and aperture settings.
Here are the results I got:

```
     Avg   Spd   ISO  Aperture
1. 0.3507, 0.10, 100, f/2.8
2. 0.5382, 0.10, 200, f/2.8
3. 0.3557, 0.10, 200, f/4.0
4. 0.2709, 0.10, 200, f/5.0
5. 0.2118, 0.10, 200, f/5.6
6. 0.1718, 0.10, 200, f/6.3
7. 0.1459, 0.10, 200, f/7.1
8. 0.1112, 0.10, 200, f/8.0
9. 0.0883, 0.10, 200, f/9.0
```

The first column is the average pixel value (straight from JPEG), averaged over the whole image, with conversion to grayscale as (R+G+B)/3. The colors are normalized in the [0..1] range by dividing the [0..255] range by 255.
So, between 1) and 2), I only change the ISO settings, the image should become twice as bright, but the average pixel value only goes up 53% (there aren't any overexposed areas).

2..3: Aperture one stop down, so the image should become half as bright, so 1) and 3) agree (the extra brightness is probably due to reduced vignetting)

3..5: Again, one stop down, 5) should be half as bright as 3)

5..8: Same, should be half (this is basically okay though).

All this is very, very strange. Btw, the results between the two cameras are in agreement, suggesting that this isn't just a peculiarity of the specific model.

This is without applying any gamma correction. The JPEG reading code is in C++ and basically follows the IJG sample code (the `djpeg` utility). Now, JPEG saves gamma-corrected values, so the pixel values should be treated as values in the sRGB color space (get source pixels, convert to [0..1], and apply the [sRGB->linear RGB transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation). Let's try that:

```
     Avg   Spd   ISO  Aperture
1. 0.1140, 0.10, 100, f/2.8
2. 0.2746, 0.10, 200, f/2.8
3. 0.1175, 0.10, 200, f/4.0
4. 0.0682, 0.10, 200, f/5.0
5. 0.0424, 0.10, 200, f/5.6
6. 0.0287, 0.10, 200, f/6.3
7. 0.0213, 0.10, 200, f/7.1
8. 0.0133, 0.10, 200, f/8.0
9. 0.0092, 0.10, 200, f/9.0
```

I also tried "plain" gamma correction (gamma = 2.2), the results are very similar to the sRGB-correction case.

So I am very, very puzzled.
Can someone please explain how the RGB intensities from camera JPEGs should *really* be interpreted as, since I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: I doubt the camera sensor is entirely linear.
In addition, it looks like you want a linear brightness value.. each pixel covers an area, so perhaps try taking the square root of your luminosity value.
You could also try converting to HSB and using the brigtess value from that.
This looks like it could be useful:
http://www.kweii.com/site/color_theory/2007_LV/BrightnessCalculation.pdf

Comment: @Pete, thanks for the pointers. Yes, I do need a linear brightness value.
However, the HSB method and the RGB vector length method of determining the luminance don't really apply to my test photos; they are almost gray, so the brightness measurement is trivial, no matter which method you use. The square root idea doesn't help either, and I also think the it is not physically correct... double the brightness, and twice as many photons should hit a photo-detector in the image sensor. The sensor itself is [inherently linear](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/dynamicrange2/index.html).

Comment: The [last link](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/dynamicrange2/index.html) also mentions a digital transfer function, which is probably what's bugging me. I'll research it more and post an update with my findings if I reach anything significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the mystery slowly unfolded as I read on.

While the camera's sensor is theoretically capable of measuring linear light intensities, it apparently does not do so, but instead mimics the behaviour of the photographic film, which has a well-known nonlinear response (e.g., see [this](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/photomicrography/filmexposure.html), figure 3).
Thus, the response curve of a dSLR is nowhere near linear, but more like this:

[image: exposure response on a digital camera]

Therefore, getting absolute scene brightness out of pixel values is impractical without precise calibration.

However, I only wanted to do brightness adjustments to photographs, and having an approximately correct brightness estimation does the trick for me, so I went on to reconstruct the transfer function of my camera (Canon 350D):

[image: log-linear response curve of Canon 350D's sensor]

The white data points correspond to different exposures at various aperture values (f/22, f/20, f/18, f/16 and so on, in 1/3 stop increments). Just as the previous graph, the X-axis is logarithmic in incoming brightness, while the Y-axis is linear in pixel values (after gamma correction). Assuming the graph is in the unit square, I also calculated an approximate fitting curve via a fifth-order polynomial:

```
(((((- 6.76219 * x) + 12.0459) * x - 5.8683) * x + 1.72338) * x - 0.148753) * x + 0.0105364;
```

for x in [0.05, 1]

So, if you've got the raw ("real") brightness, getting the pixel value would come out like this:

1. Get the logarithm of the input brightness and linearly transform it so you have 7⅓ stops of exposure in the [0..1] interval,
2. Apply the above polynomial (you need special treatment for the [0..0.05) interval though).
3. Apply sRGB compression.

Term this transform **T**, and the whole workflow in my application now works like this:

1. Treat input JPEG images with **T<sup>-1</sup>**,
2. The result values are kept in floating-point format, and treated as linear RGB values,
3. Apply **T** just before saving the results back in JPEG.

Comment: I think you should be able to get linear values out if you use raw, unprocessed data.  The CCD is the most linear device known to man (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device); camera manufacturers apply this kind of curve to the image to make the image you finally get look more pleasing.  I would try on your raw data, and see if there's a difference-- you shouldn't have to deal with these issues.

Comment: I don't think so. [This guy](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/dynamicrange2/index.html) apparently works on RAW data and the same transfer curve is visibly present even there. I haven't experimented with this myself, though. Moreover, RAW files take up more space, and I want to process literally thousands of photos (time-lapses), so the storage space requirements *are* an issue. Last, RAW files are vendor-specific, require specialized libraries to read them, and the processing could be cumbersome (and I don't want to implement a fully-fledged YetAnotherRAWProcessingApp) :)

Comment: @anrieff-- I just caution you about removing so much information.  There is quite a bit of information in the RAW that is lost in the jpeg conversion, and that loss can seriously degrade whatever it is you're trying to do.  An automatic conversion to jpg is another source of error in your process; modifying the conversion params will produce different results.  I guess the question is whether the difference will be significant.  I didn't know that commercial cameras aren't linear, though-- thanks for the link.  Scientific detectors had better be linear, otherwise lots of science is wrong.

Comment: You definitely have the right approach here. The transfer curve is completely arbitrary up to the whims of the camera manufacturer or raw processing software, so measuring it is critical. The raw data is probably linear but since you can't use it without running through a conversion the point is moot.